# Use shell reserved word if hidden by an alias

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

How do I access a reserved word if an alias is hiding it?

Here `if` works normally:

```
% if : ; then echo true; fi
true
```

After aliasing `if`:

```
% alias if=date
% if : ; then echo true; fi
zsh: parse error near `then'
```

Prefixing with `builtin` or `\` doesn't help:

```
% builtin if : ; then echo true; fi
zsh: parse error near `then'
% \if : ; then echo true; fi
zsh: parse error near `then'
```

How do I access a reserved word in the pathological case that it hidden by an alias?

Comment: Remove the alias?

Comment: did you try =if ? prefix if with =

Comment: `if` is a builtin in `csh` but not in Bourne Shell compatible shells.

Comment: @Ezwig prefixing with `=` doesn't help in either shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[schily's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/456413/143394) pointed me to [POSIX Shell Command Language section 2.3.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03_01) which says:

> However, reserved words in correct grammatical context shall not be candidates for alias substitution.

I've confirmed that both `{ba,z}sh` default behaviour doesn't follow the above.

[I asked on `zsh-workers`](http://www.zsh.org/mla/workers//2018/msg00977.html) and was directed to the option `POSIX_ALIASES`, about which the [man page](https://manned.org/zshall.1) says:

> ```
>   POSIX_ALIASES <K> <S>
>           When this option is set, reserved words are not candidates for
>           alias expansion:  it is still possible to declare any of them as
>           an alias, but the alias will never be expanded.  Reserved words
>           are described in the section RESERVED WORDS in zshmisc(1).
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use a shell that does not have this bug.

The standard says that a reserved word cannot be subject to alias expansion.

So:

```
alias if=echo
if : ; then echo true; fi
```

prints `true` with correctly written shells.

Unfortunately, `bash` is not correct here too, but `ksh93`, `bosh` and `dash` behave correctly.

To give further hints:

- a backslash before an alias name disables this alias in correctly written shells.
- a backslash before a reserved word, makes this token a normal word.

As a result `\if` disables the alias but at the same time makes it a non-reserved word.

Comment: As shown in the OP,  `\if` doesn't work in `zsh`. It also doesn't work in `bash`. Any workarounds for those shells?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer re POSIX. I found and quoted it in the question.

Comment: We had seral related discussions in the POSIX teleconferences during the last 6 months. Did you read my explanation on why `\if` does not work. Since `if` is not a builtin but part of the syntax, your `builtin` call cannot help. Do you have a real world problem this question is based on?

Comment: Not a real-world problem. I needed to disable `zsh` global aliases as they were causing syntax errors in a sourced file. I came across this question while trying to avoid all aliases in the process of saving `zsh` option `aliases` and then setting `no_aliases`.